# PnP Enable Feature not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

Ok I a working with sharepoint online where I am trying to enable open-documents in client which is not working with the following commands.

```
connect-pnponline -url "abcdefg"
Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 8A4B8DE2-6FD8-41e9-923C-C7C3C00F8295
Get-PNPFeature
```

The feature will not enable.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Not a single thing

Answer (score 0):

Feature ID for Open Documents in Client Applications by Default feature is:
8A4B8DE2-6FD8-41e9-923C-C7C3C00F8295

And your script is correct!

So try this

```
Get-PnPFeature -Identity 8A4B8DE2-6FD8-41e9-923C-C7C3C00F8295 | Enable-PnPFeature
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too and it turns out you need to include the scope flag (which seems silly because it's not an option to choose which scope you want):

> Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 8a4b8de2-6fd8-41e9-923c-c7c3c00f8295
> -Scope Site